# Error while installing Apache server

Tags: apache, installation

So, I started learning PHP. It "turned out" that I need local server or smth like that (I really dunno much about this stuff, I apologize for rude mistakes). I fond out that Apache is the most popular one. I followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOYEk6IDVCg&feature=relmfu) tutorial to install it. But when installing using shown properties, this error occurred:

[image: first one]

And than this one:

[image: second one]

I don't really understand this stuff, can you help me?
Any help will be appreciated :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 80 is probably being used by something else. Skype is the likely culprit, but to find out for sure, open up a command prompt and type

netstat -ano | findstr "80"

This shows you all of the processes listening on ports which include the number 80, but you're interested in the ones of the form x.x.x.x:80. On the very right you'll see that process' activity, followed by its PID. Take note of that number, open up the task manager to the processes tab, go to view -> select columns, and make sure PID(Process Identifier) is checked. Next, find the process that matches the PID you made note of. If you don't need it, kill it and trying launching apache again.